# objective-c how to convert xml to string?

Tags: objective-c, xml, cocoa, macos, twitter

Whats wrong with this code? it suppose to convert xml data to string and print it to the log?however it does not print anything!?

```
-(IBAction)request:(id)sender
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/public_timeline.xml"];
    theRequest   = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
    receivedData=[[NSMutableData data] retain];

    NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@", s);
    [s release];

//parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:receivedData];
//[parser setDelegate:self];
//[parser parse];
  }
```

and idea?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
receivedData=[[NSMutableData data] retain];
```

You're initializing empty data and afterwards, the url connection and url request are unused. The initialized data is empty.

Comment: Thanks,I dont know why I haven't pay attention to this obvious mistake, I should use delegate methods to receive the data, thanks it is working now :)